# SOQL ORDER BY on a text field, but not alphabetically - is this possible?

Tags: apex, soql, controller

I have a text field with 3 values:

- Outage
- Public Holiday
- Maintenance

I want the records to appear in a table based on the order here:

1. Outage
2. Maintenance
3. Public Holiday

I can't seem to get the ORDER BY to work when manually specifying the order, no problem when do a simple alphabetical order

Anyone been able to creatively solve this problem?

Full code:

```
SELECT
    Affected_Receive_Country__c,
    Affected_Send_Country__c,
    Detailed_Description__c,
    End_Date__c,
    Incident_Description_for_CS__c,
    Incident_Status__c,
    Incident_Type__c,
    Service__c,
    Start_Date__c,
    Latest_Update__c,
    Customers_Notified__c,
    API_Enabled_Disabled__c,
    Action__c

FROM ou__c 
WHERE Incident_Status__c = 'Open'
ORDER BY Incident_Type__c DESC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change type of field `Incident_Type__c` to picklist, then arrange values in desired order `Outage, Maintenance, Public Holiday` and values would be sorted in that way. From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm) :

> - picklist sorting is defined by the picklist sort determined during
>     setup.